# Selected Value Remain Save in Dialogfragment with radio Button Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to save value in Dialogfragment with other options. Once it saved but If I Reopen Dialogfragment screen value changed to "No Answer" .. It doesn't remain saved or call my last saved value.
My First Image when I select Value and save

[image]

When I reopen my dialog box

[image]

**Dialog**

```
class HeightDialog : DialogFragment() {

    interface SingleChoiceListner {
        fun onPositiveButtonClicked(list: Array<String>?, positon: Int)
        fun onNegativeButtonClicked()
    }

    internal var positition = 0
    lateinit var mSingleChoiceListner: SingleChoiceListner


    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        try {
            mSingleChoiceListner = context as SingleChoiceListner
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw ClassCastException(activity.toString() + "SingleChoiceListner must be implemented")
        }
    }


    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {


        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
        val heightArray = activity?.resources?.getStringArray(R.array.height_array)

        builder.setTitle("Select Your Height")
            .setSingleChoiceItems(
                heightArray,
                positition
            ) { dialog, which -> positition=which }
            .setPositiveButton(
                "ok"
            ) { dialog, which ->
                mSingleChoiceListner.onPositiveButtonClicked(
                    heightArray,
                    positition
                )
            }
            .setNegativeButton(
                "cancle"
            ) { dialog, which -> mSingleChoiceListner.onNegativeButtonClicked() }

        return builder.create()

    }

}
```

**Activity**

```
override fun onPositiveButtonClicked(list: Array<String>?, positon: Int) {
    val height = list?.get(positon)
    heightPosition=positon
    newHeight = "${height?.replace("cm", "")}"
    height_tv.text = height
}

override fun onNegativeButtonClicked() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter in your `setSingleChoiceItems` responsible for the default value in your dialogue.
If you want to display last selected item from this dialogue you should save somewhere this position, and later when you call this dialogue retreive your value and set it.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your last selected position in your parent activity.

Other Option you can save it in preference.

Make one Pref class.

```
 object Pref {
   private val LastSelecetedPosition = "last_selection"

   fun getLastSelection(context: Context): Int {
            return getPrefs(context).getInt(LastSelecetedPosition,0)
        }

  fun setLastSelection(context: Context, lastSelection: Int) {
    getPrefs(context).edit().putInt(LastSelecetedPosition,  lastSelection).apply()
   }
}
```

Now, when you save your selection after that set value in pref.

```
pref.setLastSelection(context,4)  //set your option at here
```

At last when ever you want to fetch your last selection than just use below line

```
pref.getLastSelection(context)
```

Hope this will help you.